# Throw exception result set closed

Tags: java, jdbc

it's a log in form 
 this code throw Exception result set is closed ... why rs doesn't contain table??
before i add << String rsusername=rs.getString("name");
                    String rspassword=rs.getString("password");>>
always printing worng username or password

how can i solve it ???

*preparedstatement has no effect on code

code:

```
final JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Log in");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            String password=passwordField.getPassword().toString();
            String UserName = textField_1.getText().toString();
            try
            {
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");   
                Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\max\\Desktop\\javaproject\\hotel");
                String sqlcheck="select * from login where  login.Name ='"+UserName+"'and login.password='"+password+"'";
                Statement s =con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs=s.executeQuery(sqlcheck);
                String rsusername=rs.getString("name");
                String rspassword=rs.getString("password");

                if(rs.next())
                {

                btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                            Hotel1 hotel=new Hotel1();
                            hotel.setVisible(true);
                }
            });

                }
                 else
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "worng user name or password");
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "class not found exception"+e);
            }
```

Comment: You need to call `rs.next()` to get the first value.  I would guess there is no first value which is why you get an error.  Where are you closing your ResultSet, Statement and Connection resources? (Unless you do this you will have a memory leak)

Comment: ok 
when i execute this query in sqlite .... retrieve the value

Answer (score 1):

You need to move up the call to rs.next like this:

```
if (rs.next ()) { 
   String rsusername=rs.getString("name"); 
   String rspassword=rs.getString("password");
```

**Try it like this:**

```
    String sqlcheck=
             "select * from login where"
             + " login.Name = ?  and login.password=? ";
    try(PreparedStatement s =con.prepareStatement(sqlcheck)) {
      s.setString(1 , UserName);
      s.setString(2, password);
      try(ResultSet rs=s.executeQuery()) {
          if(rs.next()) {
            String rsusername=rs.getString("name");
            String rspassword=rs.getString("password");
            btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
              @Override
                  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                      Hotel1 hotel=new Hotel1();
                      hotel.setVisible(true);
                  }
             });
          } else {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "worng user name or password");
          }
      }
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "class not found exception"+e);
    }
```

Comment: i move it 
but it doesn't enter (if statement ) 
printing  " worng user name or password"

Comment: Then there is no matching user - select returns no rows.

Comment: Try it without the where once (just select * from users) until that code works - then complete sql to do login check. Maybe you want to go PreparedStatement there?

Comment: work until i wrote (( login.password='"+password+"')) in where.......

when i use PreparedStatement it  throw exception PreparedStatement not supported ( after i wrote password= ...etc)